# active record in codeigniter in the case of assignment by value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

This my model function. obviously it is not best practice to mix sql query and active record together. How should I write the entire function using active record?

```
public function foo_bar_function($id, $date, $amount) {

       $this->db->where('id', $id);
       $this->db->set('date', $date, TRUE);
       $this->db->set('amount', $amount, FALSE);
       $this->db->update('table_foo');
       $sql = "UPDATE table-foo set diff = total - " . $amount . " WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
       $this->db->query($sql);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using active record you can rewrite your update query as below,Also you can use single update instead of running 2 update queries

```
public function foo_bar_function($id, $date, $amount) {
    $this->db->set('date', $date);
    $this->db->set('amount', $amount);
    $this->db->set('diff', 'total -'.$amount, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_foo');
}
```

[`See set() method of active record`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)